# Calling postgis ST_DWithin in a rails query

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

The following is being attempted in the console for a postgis enabled rails4.2 application.

```
@target = Target.last
@meter_radius = 1000
@valid_points = Target.where("ST_DWithin(#{@target.lat}, #{@target.lon},  #{@meter_radius}))
```

lat and lon are defined as decimal values. This translates into the following query

```
SELECT "targets".* FROM "targets"  WHERE (ST_DWithin(38.656679, 15.984094, 1000))
```

with the error:
`PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function st_dwithin(numeric, numeric, integer) does not exist`

I believe I need to declare the data type (geometric or geographic) for these values but am not sure how.  I am also wondering whether the ST_DWithin function can work off of the 3857 data type, even though the documentation does not state so.

*note* the @target object also has a `lonlat` attributes defined as a spatial value in postgresql with :srid=>3857, :type=>"point" defined.

**Update**

```
@valid_points = Target.where("ST_DWithin(lonlat, ST_PointFromText('#{@target.lonlat}',  #{@meter_radius}))
```

returns a result and thus appears syntactically valid.

```
SELECT "targets".* FROM "targets"  WHERE (ST_DWithin(lonlat, ST_PointFromText('POINT (15.984094 38.656679)', 3857), 1000))
```

However the result is incorrect. It essentially finds all the points of the table.  Being of SRID type, this needed to be expressed in degrees, not meters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer, leveraging the lonlat spatial point stored:

```
@target = Target.last
@degree_radius = 0.2249
@valid_points = Target.where("ST_DWithin(lonlat, ST_PointFromText('#{@target.lonlat}',  #{@degree_radius}))
```

which returns a result and thus appears syntactically valid.

```
SELECT "targets".* FROM "targets"  WHERE (ST_DWithin(lonlat, ST_PointFromText('POINT (15.984094 38.656679)', 3857), 0.2249))
```